# MVC 6 Web API generating urls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am writing an app in MVC 6 and attempting to make a web api call.  The url for the call will be http://mysite/api/Organizations/{id}/groups.  How do I generate that URL in Razor?  Normally, I use `Url.Action("Get", "Organizations")` but I'm not sure how to get the trailing /groups on it like that.

Comment: Is the web api part of your web app ? I mean same domain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have defined this specific route pattern on one of your api controllers with a Route name

```
public class OrganizationsController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/Organizations/{id}/groups", Name = "OrgGroupsRoute", Order = 1)]
    public IHttpActionResult GetGroupsForOrg(int id)
    {
        return Ok(new string[] { "groups for org", id.ToString() });
    }
}
```

You can use the `Url.RouteUrl` helper method to generate the Url (with the pattern we defined) by passing in the route name

```
<a href="@Url.RouteUrl("OrgGroupsRoute",
                                   new { httproute=true,id = 34})">Get Groups for Org </a>
```

Comment: Works like a charm.  Thank you!